# Why does the string "information" not get pluralized?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

In my rails console:

```
[10] pry> I18n.locale
=> :fr
[11] pry> "information".pluralize I18n.locale
=> "information"
```

That's the only word that I end up having a problem with.
I guess that in english, this word is uncountable, but in french it is not.

I also tried with and without the following inflectors:

```
inflect.plural /ion$/i, 'ions'
inflect.plural /information$/i, 'informations'
```

But there is no difference.

Comment: There are people who downvoted me, I'd like to know why so I can fix my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does the string “information” not get pluralized?

Because it is one of the few words that rails considers uncountable (interestingly, this list doesn't include other proper english uncountables, like "tea").

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections.uncountables
# => ["equipment", "information", "rice", "money", "species", "series", "fish", "sheep", "jeans", "police"]
```

This list of rules is *not* dependent on current locale (it is [hardcoded](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/20c91119903f70eb19aed33fe78417789dbf070f/activesupport/lib/active_support/inflections.rb#L70) in rails), so even though the word is countable in french, rails has no idea about that.

Overriding the rule works, though:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  inflect.plural 'information', 'informations'
end

# then
"information".pluralize # => "informations"
```

Comment: Is the `inflections.uncountables` list you show above is global and apply to every locales ? It seems weird that since I tried to pluralize in `:fr` it still goes into this list, no ?

Comment: @Hellfar: yes, it appears to be hardcoded in rails. https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/20c91119903f70eb19aed33fe78417789dbf070f/activesupport/lib/active_support/inflections.rb#L70